# MongoDB Driver. Though inserted data with value, but default value of class comes out

Tags: c#, mongodb

while functionizing, I want to check seed data is in collection.

But collection has data with default value of class.(eg.null/1/0/,,,)

class A

```
public sealed record A { 
    public int ID { get; }

    public string StartId { get; }
    public string EndId { get; }

    public A(int id, string startId, string endId){
        Id = id;
        StartId = startId;
        EndId = endId;
    }
}
```

seed is like

```
    private readonly A[] seed = new []{
        new A(1, "n1", "100"),
        new A(2, "n2", "90")
    };

    private IMongoDatabase MakeDatabase<T>(string dbName, string? collectionName, IEnumerable<T>? seed) {
    var client = new MongoClient(MongoRunner.Run().ConnectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);

    if (collectionName != null) {
        database.CreateCollection(collectionName);
        database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).InsertMany(seed);


        // To Check collection has right seed
        var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        foreach (var x in collection.Aggregate().ToList()) {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.Write("sfdfasd");
        }
    }
    return database;
}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the `A` class?

Comment: I added A class in content.

Comment: You need the setter (`set;`) for all properties in `A` record. Without setter, you are unable to set the value to the properties. Hence you will see those properties are with default value.

Comment: I forgot to add constructor. Event I use it, do I nee set?

Comment: Hmmm, from your screenshot, the fields don't match your `A` record *structure*. That is a possible root cause leads to unable bind value. If you try to use MongoDB compass to check the inserted data, are the data are inserted correctly? Can you share the sample document in MongoDB?

Comment: There was an issue related to use Immutable. Thank you for your kind reply :)